# What does Kx mean in this equation? [in Carnap or Russell and Whitehead's logical notation]

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic

Hope this is the right forum for this.  I am reading a seminal "mathematical biophysics" paper from 1943 by MucCulloch and Pitts, and I got into a little bit of a rabbit hole trying to understand this equation in old-style logical notation.  [image: The definition of S]

This is the equation in question: [image: The equation]

By following [this link](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/), I think I got most of it figured out, and I'm assuming `x’)` means "predecessor of x", and so the equation should be read as something like "The property S(P) holds for t if and only if P holds for Kx and t is the predecessor of x?  But what does Kx mean?  Doesn't this equation fulfill the definition if Kx were just replaced by x in the definition?

Thanks for any guidance on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the References, R.Carnap (1938) is :

> Rudolf Carnap, [Logical Syntax of Language](https://books.google.it/books?id=j6RqQtU0OKkC&pg=PA92), Routledge (German ed.1934; 1st English ed.1937).

Language II is Carnap's versione of W&R's *Principia* theory of types.

The *K-operators* correspond to the bounded and unbounded [$\mu$-operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C_operator).

The definitional axiom (it is a contextual definition) for the bounded one is (in slightly modernized symbols) :

> $G(Kx_{x \le y}[F(x)]) \leftrightarrow [ (\lnot (\exists x)_{x \le y}[F(x)] \land G(0)) \lor  (\exists x)_{x \le y} (F(x) \land \forall z_{z \le x} [\lnot (z=x) \to \lnot F(z)] \land G(x))].$

Thus, $(Kx)y[F(x)]$ reads : "$\text {the least (natural) number } x \text { less-equal to } y \text { such that } F$".

In the same way, $(Kx)[F(x)]$ reads: "$\text {the least (natural) number } x \text { such that } F$".

---

If so, the expression:

> $S(P)(t) \equiv P(Kx) (t=x'),$

where $S$ is a *functor* that applies to properties, reads:

> > "$S(P)$ is a property that holds for (number) $t$ if and only if the property $P$ holds for the least number $x$ that is the predecessor of $t$ [$t=x'$ means that $t$ is the *successor* of $x$]".

Comment: Great answer, thank you so much!