# Understanding the symbolism of Carnap's Language II

Tags: logic, reference-request, formal-languages

I'm reading a pretty old paper. The authors deem "the most appropriate symbolism [...] that of Language II of Carnap, augmented with various notations drawn from Russell and Whitehead, incuding the *Principia* convention for dots." A few sentences later, they say

> [...] we shall intrudce a functor $S$, whose value for a porperty $P$ is the property which holds of a number when $P$ holds of its predecessor; it is defined by $S(P)(t).\equiv.P(Kx).t =x')$.

This notation is new to me and I have no idea what it means. I do not understand the dots in $.\equiv.$ nor why is there a final parenthesis $)$ which has no matching left parenthesis $($. Also I do not understand the dot notation in $P(Kx).t$ nor what $x'$ stands for. Of course, this follows from the fact that I do not know anything of Carnap's Language II nor what was the language of Russell's and Whitehead *Principia*.

I googled "Carnap's Language II" and similar querys but I found nothing which teaches this symbolism. Could anyone $a.$ explain the meaning of these symbols and/or $b.$ point to a reference where I could learn the language in question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dots are only parentheses.

Comment: The source is [The Logical Syntax Of Language (1937)](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.136409); thus, quite old ... Language II is basically High-Order Logic with quantification of predicates and functions and not only individual variables.

Comment: I agree with you about the rightmost parentheses... IMO there are no correct syntax where unmatched parentheses are allowed. Leaving it aside, IMO the formula amounts to $[S(P)(t)] ≡ [P(Kx)(t=x′)]$. Maybe $x'$ is only the *successor* of $x$ (or next follower: $x+1$).

Comment: The role of $K$ is not clear to me... The part "P is the property which holds of a number when P  holds of its predecessor" is linked to $P(t)$ and $t=x'$ because this means that $x$ is the predecessor of $t$. Ok, see page 23: The K-operator is a numerical operator that  means "the smallest number for which a property holds."

Comment: Thus, it seems that $(Kx)(t=x')$ is the smallest number x such that t is the successor of x.

Comment: And see [The Notation in *Principia Mathematica*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/)

Comment: I would encourage you to pass your comments into a full answer so I can mark my question as solved. Thank you for clearing this out for me.

Comment: I see @MauroALLEGRANZA has already answered the hard part: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2605953/754923

Comment: Wow. I find it pretty shocking that that question exists, it references the exact same paper I am reading. I'm voting to close my own question with a reference to the answer you referred.

Comment: @TankutBeygu - funny... thanks!